# What anime/manga are the sword and the dog in this image from?

Tags: bleach, pokemon, gintama

[image]

I can figure the rest of this image out, but I just don't know what anime/manga the sword and the dog are from. Can someone help me out?

Comment: bleach and pokemon

Comment: [dog looks like from Gintama with Pikachu color](http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2010/088/b/4/_Gintama_Fanart_1__by_Chinchi_Commissions.jpg)

Comment: thanks, i think the dog is right, but i don't think the sword is from bleach, when i look it up, i don't find that sword.

Comment: I believe the dog is from Gintama and the sword is from bleach. This is a combination from all different kinds of manga's and anime's. I don't have the time to give a full answer but if I have some time later I will give a proper answer.

Answer (score 9):

The dog is a smaller version of [Sadaharu](http://gintama.wikia.com/wiki/Sadaharu) from Gintama

[image]

<sup>From http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2010/088/b/4/_Gintama_Fanart_1__by_Chinchi_Commissions.jpg</sup>

The colour of the dog is of course Pikachu.

The sword is the Shikai form of Zangetsu, Ichigo's sword from Bleach.

[image]

<sup>From http://de.bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Datei:Zangetsu.png</sup>

Comment: but the sword in the picture has two stings and that sword only has one D:

Comment: well this can be perspective and since it's a fan-art it doesn't has to be 100% correct but considering all other animes represented in the picture, Bleach really fits

Comment: i know, but its so obvious what all of the other animes are, so why would bleach look different from what it should? maybe your right, but i just think if it was bleach the artist would have only put one string on the sword.

Comment: maybe only the gasp is from bleach and the 2 strings shall point to another anime, but i can't tell what this should be then

Answer (score 4):

For the record, here are the rest of the references:

- The color of the dog references Pikachu from Pokemon.

  [image]
- The guy's hair references Death the Kid from Soul Eater

  [image]
- The guy's face references Goku from Dragon Ball

  [image]
- The whiskers belong to Naruto Uzumaki from Naruto

  [image]
- The hat belongs to Luffy from One Piece

  [image]
- The scarf belongs to Natsu from Fairy Tail

  [image]
- The necklace belongs to Yugi from Yu-Gi-Oh!

  [image]
- The prosthetic arm, the torn shirt and the robe are references to Edward Elric from Fullmetal Alchemist

  [image]
- The apple is probably a reference (?) to Ryuk from Death Note.

  [image]

Comment: Can someone please enlighten me on where the red hexagons are from?

Comment: @Gao: My guess is that it's from Deadman Wonderland

Comment: +1. You forgot Totoro though, and what about the face to the left lower corner?

Comment: @PeterRaeves: There is also something on the upper right corner.

Answer (score 1):

I think the sword is [Dragonslayer](http://berserk.wikia.com/wiki/Dragonslayer), Guts' sword from Berserk.

[image]

Comment: All the characters mixed into the image are from shonen or "children" anime. Berserk on the other hand is a "grown up" seinen anime, which makes this rather unlikely :(

Comment: that sword isn't right either, look at the strings. there to short in this picture

Comment: Furthuremore, there's a part of the iron not covered, whereas it's not the case in the OP's photo.

Comment: @Scientifica it certainly looks like the top part of the iron is not covered in the OP's photo too

Comment: @SamIam You may be right. If so,  then the top part of the sword would be white, which isn't the case for Guts' sword.

Comment: @Scientifica That's up for debate.  The brighter parts of that mechanical arm are a very similar shade of "white"

Comment: @SamIam You're right! What a good sense of observation!

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Hair: Soul Eater

Dog: Gintama (with Pikachu's colour)

Sword: Bleach

Background: Totoro

Body: Full Metal Alchemist

Scarf: Fairy Tail

Hat: One Piece

Pendant: Yu-Gi-Oh!

Comment: You might want to add some pictures of the original art to validate your claims.

Comment: half of this is the sword, and that sword is not a match for ichigo's sword in bleach.  The pommel is symmetrical and it's also not wrapped.